# Android Studio - ¿Como pasar datos desde una clase Adapter hacia un fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un fragment el cual tiene un recycler view horizontal con distintas vistas (TextViews). Como bien saben, los recycler view deben tener una clase modelo y otra clase adaptadora.

**Lo que quiero lograr es que al presionar un elemento o vista, se cambie el nombre de un TextView de la actividad vinculada a mi fragmento, por el nombre del txt seleccionado del recycler.**

Estoy intentando con Bundles pero por alguna razón el código simplemente no hace nada (mi aplicación no crashea, sino que el código no hace nada).

**Adjunto el código mediante el cual intento enviar los datos a mi fragment desde el adapter**

```
@Override
public adapter_recycler.ViewHolderDatos 
onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_row_recycler,null,false);

    view.setOnClickListener(this);

    final ViewHolderDatos holder = new ViewHolderDatos(view);

    holder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fragment_inicio f = new fragment_inicio();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("nombre",array_model_recycler.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getNombre());
            f.setArguments(bundle);
        }
    });

    return holder;
}
```

**Adjunto el código mediante el cual intento recibir los datos desde mi fragment**

```
//RECIBO DE MATERIA SELECCIONADA DESDE EL ADAPTER
    if(getArguments() != null){
        String nombre = getArguments().getString("nombre","Error");
        txt_materia.setText(nombre);
    }
```

**Adjunto una imágen gráfica de la situación (No hago screenshot de mi actividad porque es algo privado. Perdón por eso)**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Agradezco mucho su lectura**

Comment: Podrías poner algunas capturas de pantalla para entender mejor lo que quieres hacer?

Comment: Realmente no quiero mostrar mi actividad. Es algo privado. Lo que quiero hacer es simple y está explicado en el segundo párrafo en solo dos líneas de texto. Si aún no lo entiendes. Puedes ver estas líneas que te dicen que quiero: String nombre = getArguments().getString("nombre","Error");
        txt_materia.setText(nombre); Gracias por comentar!

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con un dibujo con el fin de entender mejor lo que estás haciendo, no veo que expliques gráficamente tu problema y es esencial en dado caso de que no puedas ejemplificar tu error o replicarlo, para ayudarte mejor al problema qu estás teniendo. ¿En qué parte de tu recycler se pone el "txt" que mencionas?

Comment: Sin problemas Fernando. Ya mismo la estoy graficando. En pocos minutos actualizo la pregunta y adjunto la imágen.

Comment: Muy bien, estoy trabajando en unos ejemplos ahora para poder darte una solución a tu problema.

Comment: Una forma sencilla de hacerlo es usando otto solo tienes que subscribirte desde el fragment o actividad y desde el adaptar hacer un broodcast del evento

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta @solamente . Podrías explicarte mejor?

Comment: Recién leo tu comentario @FernandoUrban . Espero tus ejemplos con muchas ganas. Gracias!!

Comment: el RecyclerView esta en un fragment y el textView en otro fragment? ó estan los 2 en el mismo fragment??

Comment: El recycler View está en el mismo fragment que el text View, si se te complica intenta interpretar la foto. Lo que está en otro lado es la captura del evento al tocar click en el recycler. Eso está en el adapter del recycler.

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer lo que quieres hacer sin mucho problema, y sin mucha complicación, puedes implementar, una `interface` y pasarla por el constructor del adaptador, acá tienes un ejemplo de como hacer esto, y sera mas sencillo manejar la transferencia de data como la necesitas:

**Primero creamos una `interface` dentro de la clase Adaptador de nuestro RecyclerView:**

```
public interface EventListener {
        void onEventName(String nombre);
    }
```

**Bien, luego declaramos esta `interface` en la misma clase:**

```
private EventListener eventListener;
```

**Por ultimo, pasamos este valor en el constructor del adaptador que creas para usarlo en el fragmento así:**

```
public MyAdapter(/*..*/, EventListener eventListener) {
        this.eventListener = eventListener;
    }
```

**Ahora , envías el valor usando este método dentro del `onClick` que haces en tu adaptador:**

```
holder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            eventListener.onEventName(array_model_recycler.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getNombre());
        }
    });
```

Hasta ahora solo estamos pasando el nombre por este método desde el adaptador, solo nos queda llamarlo desde el fragmento para implementarlo, esto lo hacemos así:

```
    public class fragment_inicio extends Fragment implements MyAdapter.EventListener{
       /*..*/
    }
```

Ya con esto estamos haciendo la implementación de esa `interface` para usar el método desde el `fragment`.

Ahora, Donde llenamos el adaptador con los valores, agregamos el puntero "`this`" en el campo del constructor donde pasamos la `interface` para su uso, de esta forma:

```
MyAdapter myadapter = new MyAdapter(/*..*/ , this);
```

Ya con esto solo nos queda implementar el método de nuestro `eventListener`, que el mismo `IDE` de `AndroidStudio` te va a generar cuando agregaste el "`implements MyAdapter.EventListener`", te generara algo como esto:

```
    @Override
    public void onEventName(String nombre) {

    }
```

Ese parámetro `String nombre` que te trae este método, es el nombre que guardaste en el adaptador cuando usaste el método en el `onClick`, solo te queda setearlo en el `TextView`:

```
    @Override
    public void onEventName(String nombre) {
       txt_materia.setText(nombre);
    }
```

De esta forma pasas valores desde un adaptador a un `Activity` o `Fragment` de forma mas sencilla, y si quieres pasar mas valores, o parámetros, solo tienes que crear el evento dentro de la `interface`, ejemplo:

```
public interface EventListener {
            void onEventName(String nombre);
            void onEventOtherValue(ValueType myvalor);
        }
```

y al volver al fragment te generara el método igual que el anterior para que uses el valor:

```
       @Override
        public void onEventOtherValue(ValueType myvalor) {

        }
```

Me extendí un poco pero quería que fuese lo mas explicado posible, espero te sirva para lo que necesitas hacer.

Comment: Hola david gracias por la respuesta. Me respondiste usando kotlin y yo pregunté usando java. No se nada de kotlin pero veo que no hay mucha diferencia con la sintaxis. Podrías traducirmelo?

Comment: @TomasM estoy usando java, en `kotlin` es otra forma para lograr lo que necesitas, si te fijas bien, veras que estoy usando java, cuando usas en las clases "`extends`" es que usas java, como en este ejemplo, el "`extends`" en kotlin es "`:`" y no lo estoy usando si observas bien el código. Uso todo en java.

Comment: Mil disculpas. Pensé que el "interface" era de Kotlin. Ya mismo me pongo a probar si esto me sirve!

Comment: noto un problema en esta línea public class fragment_inicio extends Fragment implements MyAdapter.EventListener{}. Porque te recuerdo que estoy trabajando con un fragment y no una actividad normal. El método del fragment es el onCreateView. Que debo hacer? Perdón por molestar pero esto ya es bastante complejo para mi!

Comment: el `fragment_inicio` es el nombre de tu fragmento, donde quieres implementarlo, en el código que colocas, a donde intentas enviar data, es a un fragmento con ese nombre, de allí lo saque, puesto que no colocaste mas código, y el `MyAdapter` es el nombre que uso para explicarte que es el nombre de tu clase adaptador de `recyclerView` que tampoco lo colocaste y por eso lo coloque como `MyAdapter` para poder explicar la idea

Comment: Realmente estoy confundido. Mi fragment tiene un onCreate dentro del cual ya hago mención a MyAdapter en donde le paso como argumentos el array con los strings que son los nombres. Quise copiar tu código tal cual pero cuando agrego las 4 cosas que me dices que agregue en el adapter, ya en mi fragment_inicio obtengo errores a las llamadas al adaptador que te mencioné porque me piden pasarle como argumentos un eventListener. Me dices que le pase un this como argumento pero en los fragments no existe el this. Asumiendo esto le paso un getActivity() y tampoco obtengo resultados

Comment: Estas pasando el eventListener en el constructor del adaptador? recuerda que tienes que pasarlo al constructor en el adaptador, y cuando lo uses en el fragmento, y necesites el parámetro que debería ir en el `eventListener` del constructor pasas `this`, debes tener en cuenta que aquí no estas pasando contexto, el `getActivity()`, es para contextos en fragments, allí te pide que pases un `eventListener`, por eso usas `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que comentaba es usar otto aqui esta la documentación oficial [otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)

En tu caso deberías utilizarlo añadiendo el siguiente código:

**Activity**

```
@Subscribe public void answerAvailable(ObjetoQueContengaElNombreAModificar object) {
    editText.text = object.nombre;
}
```

En el méodo onCreate

```
bus.register(this);
```

**Adapter**

Cuando se haga click al elemento en cuestión

```
bus.post(new ObjetoQueContengaElNombreAModificar(nombre));
```

Esta es la forma básica de funcionar si tienes dudas exponlas o revisa la documentación es muy completa y es un componente muy usado.

Comment: gracias de nuevo. No entiendo a que te refieres con "ObjetoQueContengaElNombreAModificar". Te refieres a la String que captura el nombre o al TextView al cual le voy a setear el nombre?